# Remove unnecessary files in React Native (CRNA projects)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

[unnecessary files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFLz2.jpg)

This is CRNA project.

Can i disable files and folders like metro-bundler, react-native-packager-cache, hastle-map-react-native-packager?

That files and folder appear by itself

Comment: Please paste the contents of your package.json, exp.json/app.json, .babelrc, rn-cli.config.js (if applicable), and the commands you ran to end up with the extra files.

Comment: app.json: https://jsbin.com/yodafulubi/edit?js

Comment: commands for run the project and open in expo:  (sudo) npm start

Comment: package.json: https://jsbin.com/qekemohira/1/edit?js

Comment: Interesting. I suspect you have your temporary directory set to your project directory, which is strange. You should be fine to delete those files though.

Comment: Yes, i was delete this files but then It appears again...

Comment: I think you probably have an environment variable set which is causing the react native packager to write to your project directory as its temporary directory. What is the value of the `$TMPDIR` or `$TEMP` environment variables?

Comment: I can't find that variables when i check in terminal printenv... i working on Linux, maybe different name of that variable on linux?